# Snowflake converting numeric value into HHMMSS format

Tags: sql, date, time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column that has number in it in the format of HHMMSS but the number is not consistent (not all have six digits), ex: "83455" "153651" "91251".
The number 83455 would mean 8:34 am and 55 as SS. I tried converting into varchar and use TO_TIME but the output is not the same as it is. Similarly, I also tried converting into timestamp then get the time from it but it just won't work. The output I want here would be 8:34:55, what is the best way to convert the number?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I split hours minutes and seconds and then concatenate them into time format.

```
   SELECT 
      CAST(FLOOR(col / 10000) || ':' || 
           FLOOR(MOD(col / 100, 100)) || ':' || 
           MOD(col, 100) AS TIME) AS converted_time
    FROM 
      yourtable
```

[MOD()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/mod.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! I'm trying to understand the function though, it is quite confusing to me, would you explain them to me? First, what does "||" mean in this function, is that a condition to cast them into time? What do Mod mean? And there is also a comma (,100) in the parentheses of floor/mod, what do they actually mean?

Comment: Sure, double pipe || is for concatenating strings. The rest is pure arithmetic. MOD() function calculates division and returns the reminder. So `(MOD(col / 100, 100)` will remove last two digits from `col`, take the second two and remove anything at left.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
An alternative approach is to use the built in function for this task.
[TRY_TO_TIME()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_time.html).

Sometimes the built in functions are easier to read, understand, less typing, optimized (runs faster/cheaper).

```
SELECT
 TRY_TO_TIME (DONT_WASTE, 'HH24MISS" )VOLIA 
,TO_CHAR (VOLIA, 'HH12:MI:SS AM' ) AM_PM
 FROM
   (SELECT '83455 'DONT_WASTE UNION SELECT '153651 'UNION SELECT '91251')
```

Comment: I tried that. It says :invalid type [TRY_TO_TIME(SYS_COLUMN)] for parameter 'TO_TIME:

Comment: Could you copy/paste the code you see in the picture and get same results?  A common mistake is using "MM" instead of "MI" for the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The core of this problem is the [format string](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions) was wrong

MM is Month, MI is minutes.

The first path I went down was slicing the string up, but the [TO_TIME](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_time.html)/TRY_TO_TIME both handle the smaller string of the pre lunchtime, but does not handle no hours, for that you might need to pad if you have such truncated values from number I assume:

```
select column1    
    ,try_to_time(column1, 'HH24MMSS') as wrong
    ,try_to_time(column1, 'HH24MISS') as r1
    ,lpad(column1, 6, '0') as p
    ,try_to_time(p, 'HH24MISS') as r2
from values
 ('83455'), 
 ('153651'), 
 ('91251'),
 ('1251')
;
```

| COLUMN1 | WRONG | R1 | P | R2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 83455 | null | 08:34:55 | 083455 | 08:34:55 |
| 153651 | null | 15:36:51 | 153651 | 15:36:51 |
| 91251 | 09:00:51 | 09:12:51 | 091251 | 09:12:51 |
| 1251 | 12:00:01 | null | 001251 | 00:12:51 |

Thus inline it would be:

```
try_to_time(lpad(column1, 6, '0'), 'HH24MISS')
```